# Shadowing `this` - lexical name resolution

Tags: javascript, this

EDIT: I think this isn't a duplicate; it being a hidden parameter, I wanted to ask about shadowing in relation to `this`, and lexical scoping, having read [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001414/javascript-access-local-variable-with-same-name-in-inner-and-outer-scope) re. shadowing.

I had thought that the meaning of the name `this` might be resolved kind of dynamically (in terms of scoping), so as to explain why it doesn't seem to me to be resolved lexically:

```
function foo() {return this;}
var a = {f: foo};
var b = {f: foo};

a.f() !== b.f();
a.f() !== foo();
a.f() !== window; //not strict mode
```

But then I read that every function receives `this` as an additional parameter, silently. (I realise arrow functions are different.)

Obviously `helper()` doesn't work as we might hope:

```
ob = {
  meth: function(){
    var helper = function() {return this;};
    return helper();
  }
};
ob.meth(); //Window or undefined
```

As far as I understand, rather than `this` being resolved by looking at the enclosing scope (the result being `ob`), instead the interpreter is calling `helper()` with `this` set to `undefined` (strict mode), silently passed as an argument.

So is the surrounding scope's `this` effectively being [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), hence lexical scoping is in fact in action?

Comment: `return helper.call(this)`

Comment: This has nothing to do with shadowing.  `this` is actually just a hidden parameter.

Comment: There's no difference between "*resolved kind of dynamically*" and "*passed silently as an additional argument*"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: @Bergi i edited to make the first phrase a little clearer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> So is the surrounding scope's this effectively being shadowed, hence lexical scoping is in fact in action?

Yes, one could view it from that perspective. The `this` bound to the `helper` scope shadows the one bound to the `meth` scope. (And if you had used an arrow function, it wouldn't).

However, you still need to remember that `this` is not an ordinary variable but a special keyword. It is only bound to function scopes, it's not writable, it has weird coerce-to-object semantics in sloppy mode, and it's always implicitly bound - as you say, a hidden parameter.

Unless you're trying to understand how `this` works in arrow functions (and their lexical resolution), the analogy with scopes and shadowing is pretty useless.

Comment: I'll try to hang on to the first paragraph :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Except in the case of arrow functions, `this` is never resolved lexically. It always refers to one of the following:

1. the object upon which a function was called, such as `valueOfThis.foo()`
2. the first argument to `apply` or `call`, such as `foo.apply(valueOfThis, params)` or `foo.call(valueOfThis, ...)`.
3. the DOM element, in the case of event handlers, such as `<button onclick="alert(this.tagName.toLowerCase());"/>`
4. the object being constructed, when a function is used as a constructor, such as `Foo = function(){ ... }; new Foo()`
5. the object bound to the function, if the function was created using `bind`, such as `bar = function(){ ... this ...}; foo = bar.bind(valueOfThis); foo()`
6. in a getter/setter, `this` refers to the object for which the property is being accessed or set, such as `valueOfThis.someProperty = 123`
7. `window` (usually) if none of the above cases, such as `foo()`

@Bergi provided a [great reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for all these in the comments below.

In the case of **bound functions**, the function being called is actually a different function than was passed to the `bind` method, because the `bind` method creates a new function

Comment: …or to something else. Your list is not exhaustive.

Comment: what is _this_: `[1,2,3,4,5].filter(/./.test, /[02468]$/)` here ? `div.onclick()` too.  `setTimeout(that.method,0);` too

Comment: @Bergi could you tell me what I'm forgetting?

Comment: @dandavis I don't see a reference to `this` in your code. If you're asking what `this` refers to inside the `filter` function, then it will refer to the array

Comment: @GreenGiant: just because you don't see `this` doesn't mean it's not used by a method... ` In the case shown, `this` refers to the RegExp, not the Array, since `[].filter` uses its 2nd argument as `this` on the callback.

Comment: @GreenGiant: `new`, bound functions, and probably [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @dandavis ok it wasn't clear which function you were talking about. Yes, you're right, `this` refers to the second regex when `test` is called as a callback by `filter`. But that is just a special case of #2 above. `filter` is internally calling the callback via something like `callback.apply(thisValue, ...)`