# Using a variable(global scope) in function named same as parameter of function

Tags: javascript, scope

```
let x = "Hello"
function greet(x) {
return x(/*variable*/) === x(/*parameter*/) ? 'Hello' : 'Hi'
}

greet('Some text')
```

The question is simple whether I can use the variable `x` declared in the function body when the parameter is also named as `x`? If yes, how?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001414/javascript-access-local-variable-with-same-name-in-inner-and-outer-scope

Comment: x is not a function x(/*variable*/)

Comment: It’s a principle called shadowing and is a bad idea. Inside the function you lose access to the outer x

Comment: @MWO I know x is not a function. I wrote variable in comment to differentiate between the variable x and parameter x.

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets Indeed it did. Thanks

Comment: @Adam I did thought it's a bad practice but was just curious to know if there is something to do in this kind of situation.

Comment: In this kind of situation, simply don't write code like this. Since it's all lexically scoped, you're in 100% control of your variable names.